# How to give shadow in a button like this?

Tags: html, css

In this button a shadow appearing and it looks like another button border there. I tried to use `box-shadow` property but I failed.

[image: box-shadow]

I used this CSS

```
a {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px #2CBFBB;
}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: you deleted it before. Same Question. Give me a link to the site where you got it from.

Comment: sorry..i can't . actually, i have a psd file in my pc and i crop it from there

Comment: where does the background color come from? anyway https://jsfiddle.net/qw1o376h/2/ is that what you are looking for?

Comment: maybe give the box-shadow a different color than the background to make it visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [chazsolo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45060657/1548895). It's possible to get shadow on button without shadow on text using absolutely positioned pseudoelement and CSS property inheritance:

```css
body {
  background: #76d7c4;
}

button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent; /* no background! */
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  
  position: relative; /* new */
}

button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  /* Making pseudoelement the same size as container */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* Inheriting border properties */
  border-radius: inherit;
  border: inherit;
  /* Applying filter with shadow */
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}
```

```html
<button>Learn More</button>
```

Comment: Good call - didn't think about using a pseudo element that inherits the border!

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this effect with `filter: drop-shadow` and a transparent background:

```css
body {
  background: #76D7C4;
}

button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent; /* no background! */
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}
```

```html
<button>Learn More</button>
```

Comment: almost perfect! but i don't want to shadow on text, is it possible?

Comment: hmm.. I don't believe so.

Comment: Let me add - not possible without another [pseudo]element. See Vadim's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it by combining `box-shadow: ...` and `box-shadow: inset ...`. Just adjust the `box-shadow` so it fits your needs.

**Example**

```css
body {
  background: #32DBD7;
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 35px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  font-size: 34px;
  
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), inset 3px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), inset 3px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), inset 3px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

```html
<button>Learn More</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.test { margin-top: 2em; }
a {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 darkgray;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #2CBFBB;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <a href="#">Learn More</a>
</div>
```